# Python: "LinAlgError: Singular matrix" Error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a bit new to Python, so I don't understand how to debug/fix an error that keeps popping up.

For context, I'm trying to replicate an OLS regression that calculates beta using random numbers generated on a normal distribution without using any OLS imports.

Link to my code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ltIjthQptu5Sto6H0czbSazkxxRur3eE?usp=sharing

```
dat = np.random.randn(2, T)             #Normal distribution
    
x = dat[0]                              #extract x and eps
eps = dat[-1]

y = x + eps
    
#estimate via OLS  
betaols = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(rhs.T, rhs)) * np.dot(rhs.T, y)
```

When I run this portion of my code, I keep getting hit with "LinAlgError: Singular matrix" on the line that initializes "betaols".

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could provide a minimal working example here. Like for example what is `rhs`? This is also for future reference, avoid linking to external code.